# get the number of elements in an XML document

Tags: java, xml, dom

I need to get the total number of nodes in an xml file in java ( java dom ...)
In the file below, the total number of elements is 15

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<personnes>
   <etudiant classe="P2">
      <nom>CynO</nom>
      <prenoms>
         <prenom>Nicolas</prenom>
         <prenom>Laurent</prenom>
      </prenoms>
      <age>25</age>
   </etudiant>
   <etudiant classe="P1">
      <nom>Superwoman</nom>
      <prenoms>
        <prenom>Sia</prenom>
        </prenoms>
        <age>34</age>
   </etudiant>
   <etudiant classe="P3">
      <nom>Don Corleone</nom>
      <age>28</age>
   </etudiant>
</personnes>
```

thank you

Comment: I believe your title should be “Get the number of elements in an XML document”.  Nodes are elements, attributes, text (including whitespace between elements), comments, and the document itself.

Comment: thank you for the comment. I change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following code snippet. It is worked for me.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class CountNoOfElements{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String filepath = "test.xml";
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
        int count = nodeList.getLength();
        System.out.println("Total of elements : " + count);
    }   
}
```

Comment: No need for a loop.  `getElementsByTagName` returns only elements;  that’s why the method name starts with “getElements”.  `int count = nodeList.getLength();` is sufficient.

Comment: @VGR, yes of course. Updated my answer. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Ooooh thank you for answering me. yes, it works with both methods